# Does Angular Material have CSS token / variables that we can use to access the theme colors?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

Angular 16 is introducing design tokens that we can use to customize component styles.

Are these available for all the theme colors?

I don't see them mentioned yet in the [Theme your own components with Angular Material's theming system](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components), so just curious if we are now able to do reference the theme colors at runtime?

Something like:

```
p {
   color: var(--mat-primary-default);
   background-color: var(--mat-primary-contrast-default);
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/27362

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/27369